# Books for pure cryptography.

Tags: cryptography

I am trying to find a"good" book (or a series of "good" books) which covers the following parts in cryptography:

1. Some background (such as Number Theory, Finite Fields, )
2. Classical cryptography (I would say private key cryptography)
3. Public key cryptography
4. The security models (In particlar, the constructions of protocols with security)
5. Pairing-based cryptography (the inclusion of elliptic curves in cryptography, as an example)
6. Lattice-based cryptography (I am really interested in this part)
7. Fully-homomorphic encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you this book: *A course of criptography* that you can find here https://bookstore.ams.org/amstext-40. I think it's very good and covers (some in details some not as much) all your arguments.

I recommend you also this site (https://bookauthority.org/books/new-cryptography-books) which gives you some good references (about 13 new books on criptography).

Answer (score 1):

Foundations of Cryptography Volume 1 and 2 by Oded Goldreich is a classical introduction to most of the essential concepts in cryptography. You can find the details of the book here.

[The Foundations of Cryptography - Oded Goldreich](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/foc.html)

With regard to other topics, please let me share a few good books.

- [Homomorphic Encryption and Applications](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-319-12229-8)
- [A Decade of Lattice-based Cryptography](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/A_Decade_of_Lattice_Cryptography.html)
- [Lattice based Cryptography by Jonathan Katz](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Lattice_based_Cryptography.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those too